# Update a Sharepoint metadata column using api Sharepoint with Postman

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a column with metadata and can only have the values ​​to sleep and wake up. How could I change if a column has the sleep value change it to the wake up value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get wake up term id in Term Store Management.
[image]

You could get detailed step here(Just look at how to get the specified value):

https://mariagraziamerlo.com/2016/01/04/how-to-update-a-managed-metadata-field-using-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

Comment: Since I could get a list of a term set because I have to do this automatically, I can't manually search for it in the Term Store Administration Tool

Comment: Now that you have got a list of a term set, splice it directly into the body.

Comment: But how do I get a set of terms with an api rest call

Comment: there is no rest api to get terms,you could use jsom.https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136047/sharepoint-2013-get-all-taxonomy-terms-jsom